# Why is there no speedup with multithreading for simple copying of an array?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the following code. It runs `nThreads` threads to copy floats from `data1` to `data2`. It appears to have no speedup as `nThreads` increases, even works slower. I thought that it might be related to thread creation overhead, so increased sizes of the arrays to insane values, but it still doesn't speedup. Then I read about [false sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206), but it appeared to only matter when false shared data are close enough to each other to fit in a cache line, definitely not hundreds of megabytes away.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/time.h>

static inline long double currentTime()
{
    timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    return ts.tv_sec+(long double)(ts.tv_nsec)*1e-9;
}

void mythread(float* timePrev, float* timeNext, int kMin, int kMax)
{
    for(int q=0;q<16;++q) // take more time
        for(int k=kMin;k<kMax;++k)
            timeNext[k]=timePrev[k];
}

static inline void runParallelJob(float* timePrev, float* timeNext, int W, int H, int nThreads)
{
    std::thread* threads[nThreads];
    int total=W*H;
    int perThread=total/nThreads;
    for(int t=0;t<nThreads;++t)
    {
        int k0=t*perThread;
        int k1=(t+1)*perThread;
        threads[t]=new std::thread(mythread,timePrev,timeNext,k0,k1);
    }
    for(int t=0;t<nThreads;++t)
    {
        threads[t]->join();
        delete threads[t];
    }
}

int main()
{
  size_t W=20000,H=10000;

  float* data1=new float[W*H];
  float* data2=new float[W*H];
  memset(data1,0,W*H*sizeof(float));
  memset(data2,0,W*H*sizeof(float));
  for(float nThreads=1;nThreads<=8;++nThreads)
  {
    long double time1=currentTime();
    runParallelJob(data1, data2, W, H, nThreads);
    long double time2=currentTime();

    std::cerr << nThreads << " threads: " << (time2-time1)*1e+3 << " ms\n";
  }
}
```

I compile this program with g++ 4.5.1, with command `g++ main.cpp -o threads -std=c++0x -O3 -lrt && ./threads`. The output of this program on my Core i7 930 (quad core with HyperThreading) reads:

> 1 threads: 5426.82 ms
>
> 2 threads: 5298.8 ms
>
> 3 threads: 5865.99 ms
>
> 4 threads: 5845.62 ms
>
> 5 threads: 5827.3 ms
>
> 6 threads: 5843.36 ms
>
> 7 threads: 5919.97 ms
>
> 8 threads: 5862.17 ms

Originally the program, which was reduced to this test case did a bit of multiplications, divisions and additions in the thread loop instead of plain copying, with the same performances.

Interestingly, if I omit `-O3` from the compiler command line, 1 thread appears to execute for 11303 ms while 2 threads for 6398 ms (~2x speedup), but more threads still execute for about 5700 ms (no more speedup).

So, my question is: what am I missing? Why doesn't the performance scale with number of threads in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the factor that limits copy speed here is memory bandwidth. Therefore, having multiple cores copy the data makes no difference, since all the threads have to share the same memory bandwidth.

Comment: Interesting.  That would mean the program is I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound.  I had never thought of memory access as being a type of I/O!

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be a good guess. I've tried doing `std::sqrt(1.5+timePrev[k])` instead of just `timePrev[k]`, and the times started to scale much better.

Answer (score 0):

In general, throwing more threads at a given task won't necessarily make it faster. The overhead of managing threads and context switches is expensive, so there needs to be a specific reason to go this route. Waiting for some I/O (database calls, service calls, disk access) would be one common reason to use additional threads, high-CPU tasks could benefit from threading on a multicore machine, and ensuring the user maintains control of an app with a dedicated UI thread is another case.